# UIImagePickerController overlay

Tags: ios, uiimagepickercontroller, overlay

I add a camera overlay view to UIImagePickerController. But after the photo is taken, the entire photo move down a little bit because the height of tab bar of the "Use Photo/Retake" is shorter than the tab bar of camera view.

As a result, the valid region of the photo(the box) is different between these two views. Any idea how to solve this? Thanks.

[camera view http://postimg.org/image/70hbc5oi7/](http://postimg.org/image/70hbc5oi7/)
[Use Photo/Retake view http://postimg.org/image/yo4rk3usb/](http://postimg.org/image/yo4rk3usb/)

The pic is here: http://postimg.org/image/70hbc5oi7/ (camera view)
http://postimg.org/image/yo4rk3usb/ (Use Photo/Retake view)